# Combining two numpy arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

As I read through numpy tutorials, I give myself challenges to build my understanding. I was reading through tutorialpoint.com's numpy resource when I saw in the last example that their end-product modified array was not really an array.

Bottom of page, Broadcasting Iteration example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_iterating_over_array.htm

So I decided it would be a nice challenge to try and create the same endproduct as an array. I succeeded but I was not able to use np.nditer nor was I able to utilize broadcasting although I'm sure there must be a way to utilize either/both.

Here is my code:

```
a = np.arange(0,60,5) 
a = a.reshape(12,1)
b = np.arange(1,5)
arr = np.zeros((12,2))

counter = 0
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    if counter < 4:
        arr[i,:] = np.array([a[i],b[counter]])
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = 0
        arr[i,:] = np.array([a[i],b[counter]])

print arr
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen that particular `nditer` tutorial before.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html

is the one I've used.  And I keep telling people, `nditer`, with this Python interface, is not efficient.  This page is most useful as stepping stone to using `nditer` in C code, as illustrated in the last `cython` example.

There aren't many numpy functions that use `np.nditer` (in Python code).  `np.ndindex` is one of the few.  It's worth reading its code.  `np.einsum` uses this iterator, but in compiled code.

I'll take time later to read and comment on the example in question.  Learning  to use broadcasting well is more important than using `nditer`.

```
In [212]: a=np.arange(0,60,5).reshape(3,4)
In [213]: a
Out[213]: 
array([[ 0,  5, 10, 15],
       [20, 25, 30, 35],
       [40, 45, 50, 55]])
In [214]: b=np.arange(1,5)
In [215]: b
Out[215]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [225]: for x,y in np.nditer([a,b]):
     ...:     print("%d:%d"%(x,y), end=' ')
     ...: print()
0:1 5:2 10:3 15:4 20:1 25:2 30:3 35:4 40:1 45:2 50:3 55:4
```

Equivalent plain Python iteration:

```
In [231]: for row in a:
     ...:     for x,y in zip(row,b):
     ...:         print("%d:%d"%(x,y), end=' ')
     ...: print()
     ...: 
0:1 5:2 10:3 15:4 20:1 25:2 30:3 35:4 40:1 45:2 50:3 55:4
```

`np.broadcast` will broadcast the (3,4) array with (4,):

```
In [234]: np.broadcast(a,b)
Out[234]: <numpy.broadcast at 0x9c2a7f8>
In [235]: list(_)
Out[235]: 
[(0, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (10, 3),
 (15, 4),
 (20, 1),
 (25, 2),
 (30, 3),
 (35, 4),
 (40, 1),
 (45, 2),
 (50, 3),
 (55, 4)]
```

Use `np.array(list(np.broadcast(a,b)))` to make a (12,2) array.

Or with the same print:

```
In [237]: for x,y in np.broadcast(a,b):
     ...:     print("%d:%d"%(x,y), end=' ')
     ...: print()
     ...: 
0:1 5:2 10:3 15:4 20:1 25:2 30:3 35:4 40:1 45:2 50:3 55:4
```

---

Your iteration:

```
In [251]: arr = np.zeros((12,2),dtype=int)
     ...: counter = 0
     ...: for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
     ...:     if counter < 4:
     ...:         arr[i,:] = np.array([a.flat[i],b[counter]])
     ...:         counter += 1
     ...:     else:
     ...:         counter = 0
     ...:         arr[i,:] = np.array([a.flat[i],b[counter]])
     ...:         
In [252]: arr
Out[252]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 5,  2],
       [10,  3],
       [15,  4],
       [20,  1],
       [25,  1],
       [30,  2],
       [35,  3],
       [40,  4],
       [45,  1],
       [50,  1],
       [55,  2]])
```

Oops, looks like something off, if you expect the second column to be a repeated `b`.

There are many ways of combining `a` and `b` into this kind of array.

This turns the 2d `a` into a 1d; replicates `b`  with `tile`, and joins them with `stack` (`column_stack` would have worked as well):

```
In [264]: np.stack((a.flat, np.tile(b,3)),1)
Out[264]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 5,  2],
       [10,  3],
       [15,  4],
       [20,  1],
       [25,  2],
       [30,  3],
       [35,  4],
       [40,  1],
       [45,  2],
       [50,  3],
       [55,  4]])
```